# matching and copying values from text file using python

Tags: python-2.7

```
   s =    'metacountry^AU|metalanguage^EN|metaharddrive^124gb|metabluetooth^Bluetoo'
 k = s.split('|')
#print k
 for attribute in k:
#print vals
```

for l in vals:
       print l

Comment: def Process(self, uri, document):
  filename='C:/Search/comparison/eng1.txt'
  fp=''
  FileSize=0
  if os.path.isfile(filename):
   fileStats = os.stat ( filename )
   #print 'File Size - ' + str(fileStats [ stat.ST_SIZE ])
   if fileStats [ stat.ST_SIZE ] == 0:
    return ProcessorStatus.OK
   else:
    FileSize=fileStats [ stat.ST_SIZE ]
    fp=open(filename,'r')
    for line in fp:
     attributes = line.split('|')
     
     for attribute in attributes:  vals = attribute.split('^')
      
      tag = vals[0]
      
      tag_value = vals[1]

Comment: I splited | and ^ symbol in txt file

Comment: you should edit your post to add your code there instead of the comment

Comment: s = 'metacountry^AU|metalanguage^EN|metaharddrive^124gb|metabluetooth^Bluetoo'
k = s.split('|')
#print k
for attribute in k:
    vals = attribute.split('^')
    #print vals
    for l in vals:  
        print l

Comment: Please edit your post to include code; don't simply post it as a comment.